# How to render two custom policies within the same HTML file on Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

is it possible to achieve the aimed scenario?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Product Brand Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- api.localaccountsignup section -->
    <div id="api1"></div>
    <!-- api.signuporsignin -->
    <div id="api2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally, I'd have a frontend that hosts local account signup and signup or signing, as the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 policies.

1. A Sign Up policy. It will use B2C to render the "Full Name", "Email" and "Password" fields. Use custom HTML to add 3 buttons "Google", "Facebook", "LinkedIn". Each button will link to your application: `myapp.com/<social_provider_name>`. When a user hits one of these links, the app should send the user to the 2nd policy with a respecticve `domain_hint` parameter.
2. This policy will have "Google", "Facebook", "LinkedIn" IdPs configured. Each will be configured for [direct sign in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider). The app will pass a parameter `domain_hint` based off of the users action from Policy 1, and will then cause the user to hit the Social IdP they selected.

Adding parameters using MSAL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#pass-a-custom-query-string-parameter

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, as I'm working on top of [auto-account-linking sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/auto-account-linking) I already have the "first policy" you've mentioned represented by the technical profile "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-HasEmailFlagged" and a custom HTML attached to the content definition "api. localaccountsignup".  How does the second policy should look like considering that I already have the required IdPs setup on AccountLinkSignUpOrSignin.xml? Do I really need a second policy?

Comment: Also, where can I find myapp.com/<social_provider_name> or is it just a mock uri?

Comment: `myapp.com/<social_provider_name>` is your app. You need to implement logic at an endpoint like that. Or however you want the endpoint to look like at your app so your app understands how to execute authentication with MSAL for policy2. If you are using account linking sample already, then you dont need policy2. Just add the buttons and links like i mentioned, and send the user to policy1 (it already handles `domain_hint`).

Comment: thanks for all the info. I was able to achieve the expected scenario. My current concern, however, is with the extra configuration and files that need to be maintained now. I wonder if these self-asserted fields and the 3 idps buttons couldn't be achieved using only custom policies. Something similar to the layout we have for signin or signup scenarios. e.g. (username and password input fields + idps buttons)

Comment: It can’t be done in any other way. You can’t put social IdP buttons on anything but the combined sign in and sign up” page.

Comment: I see. Would be possible to reuse the combined sign-in/up again. Something close to what I´m trying here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428808/azure-ad-b2c-invoke-a-subjouney-whenever-a-user-clicks-to-sign-up