# Azure AD B2C: Invoke a subjouney whenever a user clicks to sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to **call** a sub journey for users who intend to sign up during one of the main user journeys ClaimExchange?

For instance, how can I replace `<ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-SignUp-Input"/>`
for a "InvokeSubJourney" orchestration step?

My goal is to display the social providers' buttons once again whenever a user intends to sign up, but now with the buttons labeled as `Sign up with <IdP>`, and of course, a reference to `TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-SignUp-Input"`.

This is a piece of my user journey:

```xml
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="AccountLinkSignUpOrSignIn" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange"/>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LinkedInExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange"/>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange"/>
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>        
         <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
         <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH-SignIn"/>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LinkedInExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LinkedIn-OAuth2-SignIn" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2-SignIn" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-OIDC-SignIn"/>

            <!-- Invoke subjourney at this point -->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-SignUp-Input"/>
            <!-- ### -->
           </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Finally, the subjourney:

````xml
<SubJourney Id="IdentityProviderSelection_SignUp" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LinkedInExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH-SignIn"/>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LinkedInExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LinkedIn-OAuth2-SignIn" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2-SignIn" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-OIDC-SignIn"/>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-SignUp-Input"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>```
````

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it´s not possible to call any subjouney other than the `Invokesubjourney` type at the orchestration step.

More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671165/azure-ad-b2c-invoke-a-subjouney-whenever-a-user-cl.html#comment-686577